# Cumulate count querys with mysql and GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

In the following fictionalized example, there is the (main) table country_sales.

In each added record can be added several cars and several radios.

I need to make cumulative queries for a search/count component.

```
if ($group == 'cars'){
       $query = "SELECT COUNT (cs.id_cars) AS total, tc.desc_cars AS isname
                FROM cars_sold cs, tab_cars tc, country_sales csa
                WHERE csa.status = 1
                AND tc.id_cars = cs.id_cars
                AND csa.id_name = tc.id_name ";

}

if ($group == 'extras'){
        $query = "SELECT COUNT (es.id_radio) AS total, tc.desc_radio AS isname
                  FROM radio_sold es, tab_radio tex, country_sales csa
                  WHERE csa.status = 1
                  AND tex.id_radio = es.id_radio
                  AND csa.id_name = tex.id_name ";
}


if($cars > 0 ){
     $query .= " AND csa.id_name IN(SELECT id_name FROM tab_cars WHERE id_cars = ? )";
}

if($extras > 0 ){
      $query .= " AND csa.id_name IN(SELECT id_name FROM tab_extras WHERE id_extras = ? )";
}

$query .= " GROUP BY isname";
```

If the option is group (by) cars and the car is Ford Mustang, I get not only the number of Ford Mustang cars sold, but also a list of all other models sold.

The same is true for radios sold.

If the query cumulates cars and radios works but still displays a list of all cars or all radios sold according to the criteria GROUP BY

What I try to achieve is to get only one row with the desired count. For example and only 80 Ford Mustang.

I tried the following:

```
if ($group == 'cars'){
       $query = "SELECT COUNT (cs.id_cars) AS total, tc.desc_cars AS isname
                FROM cars_sold cs 
                LEFT JOIN tab_cars tc ON cs.id_cars = tc.id_cars
                LEFT JOIN country_sales csa ON tc.id_name = csa.id_name
                WHERE csa.status = 1 ";
}

if ($group == 'extras'){
        $query = "SELECT COUNT (es.id_radio) AS total, tc.desc_radio AS isname
                  FROM radio_sold es 
                  LEFT JOIN tab_radio tex ON es.id_radio = tex.id_radio
                  LEFT JOIN country_sales csa ON tex.id_name = csa.id_name
                  country_sales csa
                  WHERE csa.status = 1 ";
}


if($cars > 0 ){
     $query .= " AND id_cars = ? ";
}

if($extras > 0 ){
      $query .= " AND id_extras = ? ";
}

$query .= " GROUP BY isname";
```

Problem:

If I search by cars or radio, I get a single row with the desired result.

However cumulate querys for cars and radios does not work.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Pay attention. `=` is an **assignment operator** while `==` does comparisons. Programming can be a very exacting thing. Every single character matters. If you aren't careful your program will do exactly what you tell it to, consequences be damned.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, it was a writing mistake here. I'm going to fix this. In my real case it is correct.

Comment: [Try and reduce duplication in your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by figuring out what blocks of code have in common and creating common functions or chunks of code that can be shared. This query differs in only one thing: The column being counted. If you had a mapping table `array('cars' => 'id_cars', 'extras' => 'id_radio')` you could quickly convert the incoming argument into the required column, or error out if they didn't select a valid entry.

Comment: @tadman yeah, that was best put as a comment ;-)

Comment: @tadman thanks. This is just a very short example of my problem, since the query cumulates multiple values and uses prepared statements. Grouping is my main problem in this case. I considered joining the two main queries the LEFT JOIN of both, but apparently it returns wrong counts. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: At some point you'll want to pull the pin on using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),
[Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) so you can abstract this out better. I also think the way the schema is designed is working against you here, that with some restructuring it'd be a lot easier to query.